# Symfony 2 Asset images

Tags: image, symfony, assets

I want to add asset images in my views. But If i load the page the images won't load..

config:

```
framework:
    esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:      { engines: ['twig'], assets_version: "1.0.0" }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trust_proxy_headers: false # Whether or not the Request object should trust proxy headers (X_FORWARDED_FOR/HTTP_CLIENT_IP)
    session:         ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/../public_html
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../public_html
    use_controller: false
    #bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

index.html.twig

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/menu-park.gif') }}">
```

To install the assets I run:

```
php app/console assets:install public_html --env=dev --symlink
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: What's the url that you get inside your img's src attribute ?

Comment: <img src="/images/menu-park.gif?1.0.0">

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `assets:install public_html` command copies the `src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/public/` directory into the `public_html/bundles/acmedemo/` directory. So you need to refer to that url.

For instance: You have a bundle named *MvParkBundle* and you have created an image `menu-park.gif` inside the `Resources/public/images` directory, you should use this code inside twig, assuming that the front controller is inside `public_html` too:

```html
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/mvpark/images/menu-park.gif') }}">
```

If you run the `assets:install public_html` command, everything should be right.

Comment: You can use the --symlink too, but you need to change your path in the Twig template to `bundles/{bundlename}/images/menu-park.gif`.

Comment: The problem is: `app/console assets:install public_html` works, but `app/console assets:install public_html --symlink` does not work.. but why :S

Comment: Well, first of all, I wasn't. Second its more then a year ago.. thanks anyway